# How can I keep my data and use it after with node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

My problem is very simple, I need to put my data taken from the database in a variable but I don't know how to keep the variable defined. At the end of the pool the data went out and left the variable not defined.

So I have tried to make a res.send to send the data to the next :

```
.post('/route', data ,function(req, res){
    ...
});
```

but I think this is not a good idea.

```
.post('/musicbrainz/research/', function(req, result, next){
    var nomArtiste = req.body.recherche;
    var query = "SELECT idartiste * FROM artiste);";
    db.query(query, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        rows = res.rows;
    });
})

.get('/musicbrainz/results/', rows, function(req, res){
const results = rows;
    ...
```

My variable rows are undefined when it exits the db.query function.

Comment: Indeed, thats not a good idea. The only way I see to make that flow work would be using Redis Cache. You would use `/research` to set the cache and `/results` to read from it.

Comment: I'm going to try this ! Thank you !

Comment: The reason your variable is undefined is that you are making an asynchronous query to the database.  This has nothing to do with caching etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Actually its not clear what you want to achieve. You want to read the database at/research and set rows variable and then return rows in other url called /results?